# Intagram Api, redirect URI not matching?

Tags: c#, android, api, oauth, xamarin

Im making an app in Xamarin and using Xamarin.Auth to authenticate the API with instagram. The redirect url in my client and in my code is the exact same, yet I keep getting this error:
[image]

The website I am using to authenticate is:
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

I changed the client ID and redirect URI to my registered one.
My code looks like this:

[image]

I have no idea why I am getting this error, does anyone body know how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: Have you got solution?